# How to understand about Xcode error message log

Tags: xcode, nslog

```
objc[1372]: FREED(id): message respondsToSelector: sent to freed object=0x43be3f0
```

that error when i try to click on UITableViewCell and Play some move and then press back to select another index of UITableViewCell and play some movie, i repeat this step very fast and it will get some application terminate

but i dont understand about that log which line it make crash

how could i understand about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are messaging deallocated objc objects. To debug more easily, enable NSZombies:

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled